# A question on logic (related to odd perfect numbers)

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, solution-verification, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the sum of divisors of the positive integer $x$.  If $\sigma(x)=2x$, then $x$ is called a *perfect number*.

An [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) $n$ is said to be given in the so-called Eulerian form $n = p^k m^2$ where $p$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.  It is currently unknown whether there is an odd perfect number, despite extensive computer searches.

**MOTIVATION FOR MY INQUIRY**

Suppose, for the sake of our discussion, that I have the following abstract for a paper which I intend to submit to a journal (which summarizes some results about odd perfect numbers):

> In this article, we consider the various possibilities for $p$ and $k$ modulo $16$, and show conditions under which the respective congruence classes for $\sigma(m^2)$ (modulo $8$) are attained, if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$.  We prove that
>
> - $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ holds only if $p+k \equiv 2 \pmod
>      {16}$.
> - $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 3 \pmod 8$ holds only if $p-k \equiv 4 \pmod
>      {16}$.
> - $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 5 \pmod 8$ holds only if $p+k \equiv 10 \pmod
>      {16}$.
> - $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 7 \pmod 8$ holds only if $p-k \equiv 4 \pmod
>      {16}$.
>
> We express $\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))$ as a linear combination of $m^2$ and $\sigma(m^2)$.  We also consider some applications under the assumption that $\sigma(m^2)/p^k$ is a square.  Lastly, we prove a last-minute conjecture under this hypothesis.

Suppose further that the proofs of the results so presented are logically sound and correct.

**QUESTIONS**

Here are my questions:

> **(1)** Does it follow that $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 3 \pmod 8$ and $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 7 \pmod 8$ are **both** untenable?
>
> **(2)** Or does it only follow that the condition $p - k \equiv 4 \pmod {16}$ **cannot occur**?

**UPDATED MARCH 01, 2020 (12:33 PM Manila time)**

Apologies for the inadvertent bump!  But here is the [link to the preprint](https://easychair.org/publications/preprint/8rXW) of the article under discussion, in case anyone is interested.

Comment: I see no reason for $(1)$ or $(2)$ under the given informations. But clearly, if $$p-k\equiv 4\mod 16$$ should be impossible this implies that $\sigma(m^2)$ cannot be $3$ or $7$ modulo $8$

Comment: Thank you for your time, attention and comment, @Peter!  Please write out your last comment as an actual answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$p-k\equiv 4\mod 16$$ is impossible then clearly $$\sigma(m^2)\equiv 3\mod 8$$ and $$\sigma(m^2)\equiv 7\mod 8$$ are impossible as well since for those congruences $$p-k\equiv 4\mod 16$$ is necessary.